# Not able to Update the record using getsession().saveOrUpdate() method

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm using Spring 3 and hibernate 4. I'm not able to update the record using `getSession().saveOrUpdate(entity)`, but i'm able to insert the data. However using `getSession().flush()` I'm able to update the data. I don't want to use `getSession().flush()`.
Can anyone tell me the disadvantages of `flush()` and provide me alternative for `flush()`.

Answer (score 0):

Using flush completely depends on requirement and what do you mean by disadvantages.
transaction.commit() will avoid calling flush(). Also see different flush modes and you may change flush mode if you need something else.

Comment: Yes it will definitely cost, my question is why do you want to flush() when we have transaction. can you give me a reason so that this can be discussed better.